# Adding a redistributable to msi made with WiX

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, wix

I have seen many questions on how to include the .NET runtime redistributables with an installer, but I am not sure how I would go about adding a redistributable such as [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) to a WiX installer/bootstrapper? If anyone could help me or point me to a proper answer elsewhere on this site, it would be extremely appreciated. Thank you.

I am using WiX 3.5 with Visual Studio 10.

Not even sure if this is the purpose of a WiX installer. If not could someone suggest the best way to go about doing this? I have a few redistributables that need installed, but would like one installer for the end user. Thanks again

Comment: You could use a WiX Bootstrapper. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19849362/2226988) to a similar question.