# how to give my project to another person as a sofware

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I have made visual studio project for Windows Forms Application, In that I connect with mysql. Now I want to give this project to another person as a software then how to do that.
And I have to install Mysql on that person's PC?

Comment: build the installation package and add mySql as prerequisite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839600/wix-install-prerequisites-and-3rd-party-applications

Comment: This step by step tutorial may help you for resolve your issue : http://www.msdotnet.co.in/2012/06/how-to-create-setup-fileexe-file-from.html#.U0_S3fmSwno