# Running a Windows Installer inside another Windows Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm looking to create a Windows Installer package that will run an exe that runs another Windows Installer.

---

I'm putting a package together that has to install three files, an EXE, a CONFIG and an empty TXT. In addition, we also need to run the Access Database Engine 2007 as part of this process. However, when setting custom actions to just run it (with the flag /quiet) it fails because it's attempting to run an MSI inside of an MSI.

Is there any way I could somehow have it launch right after/right before or something? I've looked into WIX but honestly I'm clueless on how it would solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the WiX Burn functionality and prerequisites. Some examples are:

[WiX - Install Prerequisites and 3rd party applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839600/wix-install-prerequisites-and-3rd-party-applications)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/installing-prerequisites-using-wix-bootstrapper-project-and/

You could probably just run the setup from the Burn bootstrapper - it will do its own detection if it's already installed.

Comment: That was pretty easy to implement. I just set the current Windows Installer as a second point in the chain. Guess I was looking in the wrong place in WiX.