# Creating setup for SQL Server 2008 Express with WIX

Tags: sql-server, wix, installation, wix3.8

The command below runs successfully on the command line but when I put it to Wix Bootstrapper project it gives me an error.

The code that I run on command line is

```
setup.exe /ACTION=INSTALL /Q  /ISSVCPASSWORD="password6161*" 
          /RSSVCPASSWORD="password6161*" /SAPWD="password6161*" 
          /INSTANCENAME="aaa5554" /SECURITYMODE="SQL" 
          /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.INI
```

The code that I write into the Wix

```
<Chain DisableSystemRestore="yes">
  <PackageGroupRef Id="SqlServerExpress"/>
</Chain>
```

```
<?define InstanceName = "HyperionSSSS321312" ?>
<PackageGroup Id="SqlServerExpress">
  <ExePackage Id="Sql2008Express"
    DisplayName="SQL Server 2008 Express"
    Cache="no"
    Compressed="no"
    PerMachine="no"
    Permanent="no"
    Vital="yes"
    Name="Package\SqlServer\setup.exe"
    SourceFile="Package\SqlServer\setup.exe"
    InstallCommand="/ACTION=INSTALL /Q /ISSVCPASSWORD=test* /RSSVCPASSWORD=test* /SAPWD=test* /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) /INSTANCEID=$(var.InstanceName) /SECURITYMODE=SQL /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.INI"
    UninstallCommand="/Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) /FEATURES=SQL /Q /HIDECONSOLE">
    <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

When I run the setup file that Wix produced for me it fails

**The log is below**

```
1AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Sql2008Express
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Sql2008Express' to value 'C:\Users\BARIS~1.VEL\AppData\Local\Temp\SetupBoot_20140523174827_0_Sql2008Express.log'
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Sql2008Express' to value 'C:\Users\BARIS~1.VEL\AppData\Local\Temp\SetupBoot_20140523174827_0_Sql2008Express_rollback.log'
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i201: Planned package: Sql2008Express, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i207: Planned related bundle: {c1dddf1e-71bd-4847-b7c6-161cb0096f1a}, type: Upgrade, default requested: None, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, dependency: None
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i300: Apply begin
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\BARIS~1.VEL\AppData\Local\Temp\{19453c37-f078-45d3-939a-92a23e74184d}\.be\SetupBoot.exe' to: 'C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{19453c37-f078-45d3-939a-92a23e74184d}\SetupBoot.exe'
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {19453c37-f078-45d3-939a-92a23e74184d}, version: 1.0.0.0
[11AC:1390][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i338: Acquiring package: Sql2008Express, payload: Sql2008Express, copy from: D:\EAE_Automation\EAE_Automation\EAE_Automation\SetupBoot\bin\Debug\Package\SqlServer\setup.exe
[11AC:1390][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'D:\EAE_Automation\EAE_Automation\EAE_Automation\SetupBoot\bin\Debug\'
[11AC:1390][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i305: Verified acquired payload: Sql2008Express at path: C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\.unverified\Sql2008Express, moving to: C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\7E1E6EE9199D5AFD8117B8385E59B8EAAE724D2C\Package\SqlServer\setup.exe.
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i301: Applying execute package: Sql2008Express, action: Install, path: C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\7E1E6EE9199D5AFD8117B8385E59B8EAAE724D2C\Package\SqlServer\setup.exe, arguments: '"C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\7E1E6EE9199D5AFD8117B8385E59B8EAAE724D2C\Package\SqlServer\setup.exe" /ACTION=INSTALL /Q /ISSVCPASSWORD=enerji2014* /RSSVCPASSWORD=enerji2014* /SAPWD=enerji2014* /INSTANCENAME=HyperionSSSS321312 /INSTANCEID=HyperionSSSS321312 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.INI'
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]e000: Error 0x84c4000e: Process returned error: 0x84c4000e
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]e000: Error 0x84c4000e: Failed to configure per-user EXE package.
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i319: Applied execute package: Sql2008Express, result: 0x84c4000e, restart: None
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]e000: Error 0x84c4000e: Failed to execute EXE package.
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i351: Removing cached package: Sql2008Express, from path: C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\7E1E6EE9199D5AFD8117B8385E59B8EAAE724D2C\
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {19453c37-f078-45d3-939a-92a23e74184d}
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i352: Removing cached bundle: {19453c37-f078-45d3-939a-92a23e74184d}, from path: C:\Users\baris.velioglu\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{19453c37-f078-45d3-939a-92a23e74184d}\
[11AC:32FC][2014-05-23T17:48:29]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x84c4000e, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrapping SQL Express from WiX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930854/bootstrapping-sql-express-from-wix)

Comment: @TomTom Maybe thats the same code but I got an error and that subject doesnt mention about it. I think this makes them different.