# Will my customers need SQL Server Express installed in order for my WiX installer to install the SQL Server database for my software?

Tags: c#, installation, wix, sql-server-express, wixsharp

I'm using Wix# to install my software and am running a script to install the database used by my software.

Will users installing my software need to have SQL Server Express or some alternative installed in order for the script to run successfully?

If so, how can I use Wix to chain the installation of SQL Server Express with the installation of my software.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Will users installing my software need to have SQL Express or some alternative installed in order for the script to run successfully?` in short, yes, how else would your scripts run and create the db? Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930854/bootstrapping-sql-express-from-wix) maybe exactly what you need with the concern of using `Wix` installer to install sql server express etc.

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB might be an option, it's very lightweight